# Adding new attributes to a screen

Tags: layout, data-tables

I am trying add three new attributes to the screen. I am very much confused and not sure where to add would be best for the below screen. Please suggest. Also if you can suggest how it would look like, should it be best if inside a rectangular box or border or should it be best if written directly
The three attributes are:
Delivery Date: 16 Dec 2022
Delivery Time : 11 PM
Pre-Order

[image]

Below is what I thought but would need your suggestion too.

[image]

Comment: The 3 attributes will be there for all the items numbered 1,2,3 etc

Comment: Can someone help me here please? Let me know if you can't understand something in my question.

Comment: Modified my question to add a diagram of what I was thinking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance you can prioritize the information? The current ui seems pretty stuffed. Adding these additional values will lead to less items per page, which reduces the value of a list overview. The user needs to scroll more. Displaying the potentially secondary information after a tap could solve this.

Other than that your draft seems ok, although the original ui could need some "help". Avoid thin lines to group things, prefer background to display grouped things. Keep foreground/background contrast in mind.

Avoid fancy text styles (like underlining).

Comment: I think the information in the draft is all needed information and can't be removed. I also have a view button on each list when there is click on it. I am not understanding how to display grouped things using background. All other points seems helpful to me.

Comment: @puchu Compare these two: https://i.imgur.com/7RNDepw.png 
The lower image does a better job and indicating which elements have a connection (grouped). There is also some science about this called Gestalttheorie (german). It's about how our brain makes connection between visual entities (low distance, same background, etc. ...)

Comment: Nice. Got it. Thank you for explaining.